# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected<200> but was <500>

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am getting this erorr while writing test case for controller method.
I know status should be ok but getting InternalserverError.
Don't know where I am doing mistake.
Error Maybe because of I am passing Project entity in pathvariable and writing test case for string projectId. I am not sure.

**Controller:**

```
@ApiOperation
@GetMapping("/projects/{projectId}/capabilities")
public OEMCapabilitiesDto getProjectOEMCapabilities(@PathVariable("projectId") @NotNull Project project) { 
        return capabilityService.getProjectOEMCapabilities(project); 
    }
```

**Test:**

```
@Test
public void testGetProjectOEMCapabilities() throws Exception {

        OEMCapabilitiesDto oemCapabilitiesDto = new OEMCapabilitiesDto();

        Mockito.when(capabilityService.getProjectOEMCapabilities(Mockito.any(Project.class)))
                .thenReturn(oemCapabilitiesDto);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/api/projects/{projectId}/capabilities", "5f35c618548e36161c9be16b")
                .param("projectId", "5f35c618548e36161c9be16b")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("send all the required data with project");

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
```

I am getting `MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException` in console.
Failed to convert value of type '`java.lang.string`' to required type ' `models.projects.Project`'.

Comment: How should the string be converted to a `Project`? If there is a converter involved you would need to register behavior as mock for that as well. Also why send content? There is nothing in your controller reacting to that.

Comment: I tried sending content . Though  .content is used to send object through @reqeustbody annotation.

Comment: You get an error, a String isn't a Project. So unless (as mentioned0 you haven't added a specific `StringToProjectConverter` (or the Spring Data `StringToEntityConverter` or whatever that is called) no automagical conversion will take place. \